# Controlling motor EMI - more ferrite turns or shorter cables?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, emi-filtering, ferrite

In wiring up a small robot, powered by two BLDC motors (of the "hoverboard" variety), I was going to shorten the leads a bit, and wrap them one turn around a soft-core ferrite for EMI supression.

Then I thought: wouldn't it be better to leave the wire longer and just wrap it more times through the ferrite?

What is the appropriate trade-off?

[image: robot and motor chassis]

Comment: Testing will show the appropriate tradeoff. (But shorter wires will tend to reduce power losses)

Comment: Believe it or not, adding turns can become counterproductive because of capacitive coupling from turn-to-turn. The high frequency attenuation gets reduced when you add more turns. Or can get reduced. So it is best to have a notion of what frequency you are trying to knock out and a chart for the ferrite showing impedance curves for various numbers of turns.

Comment: https://www.we-online.com/katalog/datasheet/74270117.pdf The datasheet shows that 2 turns is counter productive beyond 500Mhz, interesting, thank you!

Comment: Not too bad. You may not have anything radiating at 500 MHz and above. So two turns might work for you in this case with that ferrite.